# Moving textfield value in dialog box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having a button and a text field and textarea.Now what i was trying to do is that on click of button move the values of textfield and textarea into a dialog box where both can be edited.

So i wrote the following code for it :

In html :

```
<div id="dialog"></div>
<input type="button" value="EDIT" id="editbutton" name="editbutton" class="editbutton" style="float: right;"></input>
<input type="text" value="mytextvalue" id="edittitle" name="edittitle" class="edittitle" style="visibilty: hidden;"></input>
<textarea value="mytextarea" id="editsubject" name="editsubject" class="editsubject" style="visibilty: hidden;"></input>
```

In jquery i did something like this :

```
$('.editbutton').click(function ()
        {
           $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                modal: true,
                title: "Edit Your Question",
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                resizable: false,
                buttons: { 

                "Edit": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                callback("1");
            },
               "Discard": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback("2");
            }

            }            
    });
});
```

Javascript callback function :

```
function callback(value,RowId) {

if (value=="1") {
    alert("edit");

} 
else if(value=="2"){

    alert("Rejected");
}
}
```

But my problem is to show the textfield and textarea in editable form in dialog box.Please help

Comment: you mean you want to show yout text input like this `$('#edittitle').show()`

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Yeah but in input type format.Means A label title : then textfield with the title contained in it.Which can be edited

Comment: sorry i can't understand you. Btw i don't know if you notice that your ending tag for `<textarea>` is `</input>` , maybe typo?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña yeah its tyo error..And am saying that suppose i am having a page and these two hidden fields then i want that these values to be displayed in dialog box in textfield and textarea so that i can edit them on click of edit button

Comment: @DrixsonOseña See my problem is that i had got the values in jquery function but i dont know how to get in dialog box that is $('.editbutton').click(function ()
            {
                var qtitle=$('#questiontitle').val();
                var qtext=$('#questiontext').val();
                $("#dialog").html("Title: <input id='myquestiontitle' type='text'><br><br>Question :  <input id='myquestion' type='text'>");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code in your last comment from:

```
var qtitle=$('#questiontitle').val();
var qtext=$('#questiontext').val();
$("#dialog").html("Title: <input id='myquestiontitle' type='text'><br><br>Question : <input id='myquestion' type='text'>");
```

to:

```
var qtitle = $('#edittitle').val();
var qtext = $('#editsubject').val();
$("#dialog").html("Title: <input id='myquestiontitle' type='text' value='" + qtitle + "'><br><br>Question : <textarea id='myquestion'>" + qtext + "</textarea>");
```

This gets the values from the hidden input fields `edittitle` and `editsubject` and puts them into the editable input fields in the dialog.

Note how I've changed the second input field in the dialog to a textarea so it's consistent with the hidden input fields.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P5Y2X/) for a Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Create dialog outside the click events.
onclick just fire those callbacks.